# Xfce 4 LCD brightness control granularity

Tags: power, lcd, xfce

In Xfce 4 (version 4.8 to be specific) is there a way to adjust the granularity of the on-screen brightness control that shows up when I press the appropriate hardware key on a laptop? The brightness levels are too few (only 5 steps), while I know for sure in previous OS (Debian 6 with GNOME 2) we can do more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the number of steps is currently hardcoded in the xfce4 power manager (xFPM).

But compounding that, there is a "bug" affecting my laptop--because when the brightness key is pressed, not only the laptop hardware changes the brightness, the XFPM also increases/decreases one more notch to the brightness level.

For this bug, consult:

http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=29952#p29952